# Adding a sub list within a list item within SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

Any idea of how to add a sub-list to a list item?

I need a list item to contain more complex list items, can this framework support this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Lookup field to list A that will reference list B.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for but something similar can be implemented using the lookup list.